# Rails Asset Pipeline Minify Changing 4 Byte Unicode Characters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, emoji, astral-plane

I am using http://code.kwint.in/emoji/ to convert unicode iOS emoji characters to images in my Rails app.

It works fine in development, but when precompiling assets for production, the unicode character codes are changed.

For instance, they go from `"ðŸ˜„"` to `"ï˜„"`.

How can I prevent this change from happening, as it breaks the emoji.js script I linked above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by an updated version of Rails 3.2